# upgrade from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to upgrade my rails project from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2, but, when I swapped ruby versions in RVM, I had same issues getting the app started. (mostly with mysql (which... 64bit mysql on mac (any version) is a pain to set up, and almost impossible))...

But anyway, aside from mysql problems, is there anything I would need to change in my code that is no longer supported in 1.9.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is way too many subtle changes to cover in something like SO, but this covers it quite well (I'm not involved in any way):

http://www.rubyinside.com/19walkthrough/

Assuming you're using fairly standard Ruby there shouldn't be anything which will cause problems, but I'm sure your tests will point out anything that needs fixing.